# Why do I only get one result from psql query in rails when pgadmin returns everything I expect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pgadmin-4

```
select sum(table_3.col_1) as number,
(CASE
    when table_1.line_1 ~* '(?i)City\s*(\d+)' then 'C' || (select (regexp_matches(table_1.line_1, '(?i)City\s*(\d+)'))[1])
    when table_1.line_2 ~* '(?i)City\s*(\d+)' then 'C' || (select (regexp_matches(table_1.line_2, '(?i)City\s*(\d+)'))[1])
    when table_1.line_3 ~* '(?i)City\s*(\d+)' then 'C' || (select (regexp_matches(table_1.line_3, '(?i)City\s*(\d+)'))[1])
    when table_1.line_4 ~* '(?i)City\s*(\d+)' then 'C' || (select (regexp_matches(table_1.line_4, '(?i)City\s*(\d+)'))[1])
    when table_1.line_5 ~* '(?i)City\s*(\d+)' then 'C' || (select (regexp_matches(table_1.line_5, '(?i)City\s*(\d+)'))[1])
    when table_1.line_6 ~* '(?i)City\s*(\d+)' then 'C' || (select (regexp_matches(table_1.line_6, '(?i)City\s*(\d+)'))[1])
    when table_1.line_7 ~* '(?i)City\s*(\d+)' then 'C' || (select (regexp_matches(table_1.line_7, '(?i)City\s*(\d+)'))[1])
    when table_1.line_8 ~* '(?i)City\s*(\d+)' then 'C' || (select (regexp_matches(table_1.line_8, '(?i)City\s*(\d+)'))[1])
    else 'City'::varchar
 end
) as string_result
from table_1
join table_2 on table_1.id = table_2.table_1_id
join table_3 on table_2.id = table_3.table_2_id
join table_4 on table_3.table_4_id = table_4.id
where table_4.id = 2
group by string_result
```

When I run the above query in pgadmin, I get all the information I am expecting. over 20 rows. But when I run this in rails using a heredoc and `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` I only get the last row returned. I've done this almost exact same thing(different data of course) in other projects with great success. I'm at a loss at to why here only one row is returned when run in Rails

**UPDATE:** I was able to figure out **why** this is happening, but still having issues correcting it. The problem is that when the query is passed into the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` it is escaping the space and digit requirements of my regex. I'm still going through the postgres pattern matching docs, but I have a hard time with regex's at the moment since I'm still pretty new at using them. But I'm trying to capture the digits in strings matching something like `'City 24'` where it matches with City case insensitvely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally starting to wrap my head around regexes. I was finally able to solve my issue. It was the digits capture. It worked in pgadmin with `(\d+)` but when passed through the `ActiveRecord::Base.connections.execute(sql)` it didn't work for some reason. The fix was to give it a range with `[0-9]` and since the `+` is simply one or more I gave it `{1,2}`. So now the regex is `(?i)City\s*([0-9]{1,2})` This will match the string case insensitively for `'City'` followed by any number of spaces. And the will grab the first two digits after that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the results like array. Need to use `each` method.

Example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).each |row|
  p row
end
```

What you can do is

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all
```

This will return you an array of the results.

For some reason, the results from PostgreSQL are not an Array, while other DBs return Array. Either of those should work.

Comment: Ya, I know that what is returned is not an array. I usually do `sql_results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` and then iterate through like `sql_results.values.each { |tuple| ... }` and then access the tuple with `.first` or `.last` Still giving me just the last result. I've done this before with no issue.